# Sum over momentum states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, momentum

In our lecture we used quite a couple of times that the sum over momentum states can be approximated by an integral over them.

But instead of substituting $\sum_p \rightarrow \int d^3p$, we replaced $\sum_p \rightarrow  \frac{V}{h^3} \int d^3p.$ Now I think that the motivation for this $h$ is to avoid a problem of units, but I don't see where this $V$ comes from?

Comment: iirc that is roughly estimating the number of states in a volume of $\text d^3p$.

Comment: ... also to avoid a problem with units?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider the free Fermi gas confined in a $1D$ box of length $L$. The (box normalized) wavefunction is $\psi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}e^{ipx/\hbar}$. If we impose the periodical boundary condition, $\psi(0)=\psi(L)$, we get $p=nh/L$, where $n$ is an integer.

Now we want to count the number of states whose momentum is less than $p_F$. i.e:
$\sum_{p<p_F}1$ , we get the number $N=Lp_F/h$.

If we want to use the integral instead of sum to do the job, that is:$N=\mathrm{const}\int_0^{p_F}1$, then you find that constant should be $L/h$.

Comment: but the equation is still correct for arbitrary geometries, right?

Comment: @XinWang Yes, I think so

Comment: @XinWang You probably got this by now: It's not true for all geometries, but who cares about some silly edges and the bordelrine effects which arise from the non-rectanuglar geometry if the material sample is huge with billions of billions of particles.